# How to write Helper class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a problem when use `typeScript` with `angular2`.
I want create one `helper.ts` file exports many classed/functions common to re-use.
But `Helper class` need import others service in constructor, so that when another class import `Helper class`, It have to set param is those service. I don't want this.

How I can write `Helper class`, that I can use anywhere when `import {Helper} from ..`

This is my sample:
Helper.ts

```
import {TranslateService, TranslatePipe} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import {Inject, Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
    providers: [TranslateService]
})

export class Helpper {
    public trans;
    public lang;
    public properties;

    constructor(trans: TranslateService) {
        this.trans = trans;
        //This is variable for translate function 
        this.lang = this.trans.currentLang;
        this.properties = this.trans.translations[this.lang];             
    }

    translate(key) {
        return this.properties[key];      
    }      
}
```

RenderTab.ts

```
import {Component, Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Helper} from './helpper'

@Component({
    providers: [Helper]
})

export class RenderTab {
    public helper;

    constructor(helper: Helper) { 
        this.helper = helper;
    }

    render() {
        var test = this.helper.translate('string');
    }
}
```

HomePage.ts

```
import {Component, Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {RenderTab} from './RenderTab'

@Component({
    selector: 'div',
    templateUrl: './HomePage.html',
    providers: [RenderTab]
})

export class ColorPicker {
    public renderTab;

    constructor(renderTab: RenderTab) { 
        this.renderTab = renderTab;

        var test = this.renderTab.render();
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First of all `class Helper` should be a service `class HelperClass`, which should be injectable.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {TranslateService} from "ng2-translate";

@Injectable()
export class HelperService {
   constructor(private http: Http, private translateService: TranslateService) {

   }

}
```

Now you can simply inject this helper and use it in any component you like.

```
import {HelperService} from "./helper.service.ts";
@Component({
   ...
})
export class MyComponent{
   constructor(public helperService: HelperService) {}
}
```

Update: You need to add the service in providers array of the root module for it to work, or for angular6+, the service can be provided as follows

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HelperService {
   ...
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make the helper class static so we dont need to add helper as a property and can instead do something like Helper.whatever()?

Comment: @DanHastings You can use function for this, or create an object with values and functions. e.g. `const Helper = { whatever: (a) => { a + 1} }`

Comment: Good answer.. Just to point that according to the naming convention it should be service name: `HelperService` and file name: `helper.service.ts`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero updated the the answer, thanks

Answer (score 73):

**Helper classes should only contain static functions or variable, if not they are not different from services.** *Please Correct me if I'm mistaken.*

One  of ways to create Helper class without `Injectable` or adding it to `providers` is posted here [Thanks to k7sleeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37659978/452708)

Copying the code from the mentioned post for quick reference.

`utils.ts` :

```
export default class Utils {
    static doSomething(val: string) { return val; }
    static doSomethingElse(val: string) { return val; }
}
```

Usage:

```
import Utils from './utils'
export class MyClass {
    constructor()
    {
        Utils.doSomething("test");
    }
}
```

But reading more about this, it makes sense to **inject them through `Injectable` and `providers`**, but I would ***still have all the methods as `static` and the class without `constructor`***

Comment: Neat ! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: How would you inject the class and keep the methods as static? If you inject it, you cannot use any static member, as you are getting an instance (named let's say `utils`), and you would still have to use `Utils.doSomething`.

Comment: why use `class` when you can export the functions directly?

Comment: why we need to use Injectable?

Answer (score 7):

Your Helper class corresponds to a service and since you want to inject another service in you need add the `@Injectable` decorator (not the `@Component` one):

```
Import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class Helper {
  (...)
}
```

Since it's part of dependency injection, all parameters of its constructor will be provided by Angular2 itself. You don't need to provide them by your own and instantiate yourself this class to be able it. Simply inject it where you want to use it...

You need then to the corresponding provider at when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ Helper ]);
```

Or at a component level but can only be used within processing triggered by the component.

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ Helper ]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  (...)
}
```

For more details about dependency injection and hierarchical injectors, you could have a look at this question:

- [No provider for ObservableDataService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484714/no-provider-for-observabledataservice/35489134#35489134)