# Helpers / Traits in angular 2 typescript

Tags: php, angular, typescript, traits

I belong to the `php`, `Laravel` and new starter on `angular` and `typescript`.

**I want to know whether there are some `Traits` and `Helpers` like the `php`.**

I have seen that there is the `declined` proposal:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/311

Also someone have tried to implement the `Helpers` as `Service`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35666878/3887342

**What is the best way to write `Helpers` and `Traits` if available?**

Comment: You might want to look into [mixins](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) instead. There are more [specific](http://shout.setfive.com/2015/05/18/javascript-mixins-in-angularjs/) angular examples flying around.

Comment: @R.Chappell I understood the mixins but what if the functions in the main mixin class changes? For the instance in this example:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html
if the functions get added or removed in the specific mixin class, we do need to remove or add on the implemented places. Isn't that more task to do??