# Node.js crypto.randomBytes() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-crypto

For some reason a function I am calling is apparently *not a function*.

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.15.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const crypto = require("crypto");
undefined
> x = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex")
Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function
```

Documentation for [randomBytes()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandombytessize-callback).

Is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: Tested this excerpt on v17, works fine. Also checked the docs for `randomBytes` in v14.15, seems to exist, the module in itself seems to be around for a long time now. Try renaming the variable `crypto` to avoid name shadowing but appart from that, this is very cryptic.

Comment: I like your pun. Yeah, it's quite strange :?

Comment: I have tested your snippet against the exact version of Node (`docker run -it node:14.15.1-slim node`) and was unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try logging crypto, just to check it's the right module that is imported: `console.log(crypto);`, and compare it with the official docs, you should be able to see every function and constant mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I had this issue with nodejs >= 19 and I also tried with the very very old node version 14.15.1 and I was not able to reproduce it. Are you sure you are using nodejs 14 ?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same error in the command line: `Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function`

This did NOT work for me:

```
$ node
> require("crypto")
> crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex")
```

Crypto and randomBytes have to be called in the same command:

```
$ node
> require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex')
```

The output is something like this:

'7a3161b8c92dbf26f0717e89edd27bf10094d2f5cc0f4f2d70d08f463f2881db'

After a good bit of searching, I finally found the solution here:
https://massimilianomarini.com/2020/04/random-string/

Comment: Did you use nodejs >=19 ?
Because it seems this happens only in node versions newer than 18.x.x 
and only when you are trying to use the crypto module in nodejs REPEL 
https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl

Answer (score 2):

If you attemped to create a `token`.

You can just type the following command in your nodejs cli:

`crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');`

Answer (score 2):

For all who is NodeJS and seeking for answer:

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems getRandomBytes() function got removed. I read some disclaimers that it is not very secure.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto is clustured with deprecation messages so altough most upvotes here under https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856177/828184 it does no longer seem state of the art to me.

Before I could simply use (like you but no longer after package updates)

```
import crypto from "crypto";
const token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
```

But crypto now only has getRandomValues() and I think it is not a replacement.

Only answer nr 3 with also a lot but not as many upvotes gave me a working version https://stackoverflow.com/a/25690754/828184. So maybe also try:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
const token = nanoid(64); //instead of crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex')
```

And leave an upvote there if it works because.

Comment: The question is referring to the nodejs builtin crypto module not the npm module.

Comment: The linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856177/828184 is actually still state of the art for nodejs (except for using var, replace it with const), especially on servers where you should use the async version of randomBytes (by providing the callback, or using nodejs util.promisify)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, after that, I upgrade the node js version 14 to 16, and Its works for me. Please try to upgrade the node js version.

*Ubuntu Install:*
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-debian/

*Windows Install:*
https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v16.16.0/

*Mac Os Install:*
https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-nodejs-tutorial-mac-os-x/